# Stick a div to the right border of a div defined later

Tags: css, html

I have a following divs defined in source:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="right">Right</div>
    <div id="left">Left</div>
</div>​
```

I cannot really reorder them, so I have to play with CSS so that they appear on the page as follows:

```
+---------------------+
| container           |
| +-------+-------+   |
| | left  | right |   |
| +-------+-------+   |
+---------------------+
```

The challenge is that contents of #left div may be of arbitrary width and whatever the width is, I need the #right div to stick to the right border of #left div. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Any help appreciated!

Also, there is a small constraint: I need both of #left and #right align to the left of border of the #container div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `float: right` to move `div#right` and `div#left` to the correct sides. That should also align the right side of `div#left` to `div#right`.

```
#right, #left {
    float: right;
}
```

[JS Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MV7pB/2/)

Comment: Sounds interesting. Is there any way I can make this two together align to the left of the container div?

Comment: @Karol Are you able to wrap `div#right` annd `div#left` in a wrapper div? If so, you could float that to the left.

Answer (score 0):

In your css, try floating them both to the right, like this:

```
#left,#right { float:right; }
```

**Complete CSS**

```
 #container { 
      background:#ddd; 
      width:200px; 
      height:100px; 
 }

 #left, #right { 
      float:right;  
 }

 #left { 
      width:30%; 
      background:green; 
 }

 #right { 
      width:70%; 
      background:blue; 
 }
```

[Here's the example in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qakVd/)

**Aligning them both to the left**

If your not using fixed percentage widths (or no widths at all), this will result in both `div#left` and `div#right` being floated to the right like so:

```
+---------------------------------+
| container                       |
|             +-------+-------+   |
|             | left  | right |   |
|             +-------+-------+   |
+---------------------------------+
```

If you would like to align them to the left, wrap them in a container div:

```
<div id="container-inner"> ... </div>
```

And apply this css:

```
#container-inner { float:left; }
```

Resulting in:

```
+---------------------------------+
| container                       |
| +-------+-------+               |
| | left  | right |               |
| +-------+-------+               |
+---------------------------------+
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#container{
    margin:10px 10px;
}

#left,#right {
    float:left;
    padding:0px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#000000;
}
#right{
background-color:#f1f1f1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Better Answer

Allow `#right` to set edge of `#left`, while still giving flexibility to `#left` by using a trick with `overflow: hidden` ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MV7pB/10/)):

```
#right {
    float: right;
}

#left {
    overflow: hidden; /* this causes non-floated `left` to behave different */
}
```

### Original Answer

I would expand upon Rich and JSW189's answer as, I [do not like the possibilities](http://jsfiddle.net/MV7pB/3/) of just floating them right. If you can, do that, but then float the container left ([see the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MV7pB/4/)), which requires that no `width` be set on container, else there is a problem again ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MV7pB/5/)):

```css
#container {
    float: left;
}

#right, #left {
    float: right;
}
```

Of course, ***there are applications where this will not be possible*** (like when you want `width` on the container.